# What is the difference in redirect from '/' and '/anything' in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to redirect user from `/` to `/info` if he has an update in state. 
Everything works fine if a redirect is necessary form `/anything` to `/data`, counting the same component, that is under `/`, but if the redirect is conducted from `/`, but not from `/home` it fails, and remains on the same component. So the line under `<Redirect to={'/info'} />` is visible.
What is the difference in that, and can I simply redirect from `/`?

These are pure functional components and contain no other things, except markup.
App component:

```
function App() {
  return <div className={'app'}>
     <PerfectScroll>
      <main className={'contentArea'}>
       <Router history={history}>
         <Route exact path={'/'} component={Select} />
         <Route path={'/home'} component={Select} />
         <Route path={'/info'} component={Info} />
         <Route path={'/summary'} component={Summary} />
         <Route path={'/thank-you'} component={() => <h1>Thanks</h1>} />
        <Redirect from={'*'} to={'/'} />
       </Router>
      </main>
     </PerfectScroll>
  </div>
}
```

Select component:
I can see "Hey" when redirecting from `/`

```
function Select {
 return <>
  <Redirect to={{pathname: '/info'}} push/>
  <h1>Hey</h1>
 </>
}
```

Browser history:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

Comment: What kind of difference you expect? Nothing different about redirect with root path or /anything, given path simply does not change the functionality. Did you tried to do something and it did not function?

Comment: I might've explained myself poorly, the problem is I can't redirect from root, and can redirect from '/anything'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Redirect, Simply add multiple route in the path

Example:

```
<Route exact path={["/","/pathName"]} component={yourComponentName} />
```

**Update**
If you want the redirect to work if there is no route found then you need to do it like this

```
 <Route path="*" component={Select} />
```

Comment: I see what you mean, and thank you for this info, but the problem is I can't redirect from '/' for some reason, and can redirect from every other route.
I don't have problems with '/' and '/home' for the same component.

Comment: Oh sorry, Yeah that's because of this line of code  <Redirect from={'*'} to={'/'} />

Remove this and you'll be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented your example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-8obur?file=/index.js), only thing i've changed is Select component that wrapped with React Fragments (`<></>`) as it was working unstable. Switch component check for the first child and Fragment might be breaking it.

```js
function Select() {
  return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/info" }} push />;
}
```

If i understand your logic, it should be working here.
Check the code : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-8obur?file=/index.js